# Use of "There is" or "there are"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

**There is** or **there are** family ?

I am confused, because the family consists of several people in it.

Comment: In what context do you need to use the phrase? We say "There is a family called Smith living next door", but you can also use _family_ as an implied plural to mean 'members of my family' - "I am going to visit family in London."

Comment: I downvoted because you haven't provided any research or any context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use is or are after the word family?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128472/should-i-use-is-or-are-after-the-word-family) Also [Family do or does?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/) AND [Does it make sense to say “My family is vegetarian” or “My family are vegetarians”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126809/) AND [My family ( is / are ) all doctors](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93002/) AND [“Are” vs. “is” after “parents and the family”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18417/)...

Comment: (There will also be dozens more questions asking essentially the same thing, but focusing on words like ***company, police, government,...***)

Answer (score 1):

The link ColleenV provided in the comments is relevant, but it is not the whole story. I see three separate issues.

First, there is the use of singular or plural verbs for collective nouns like *family*, and as the linked question discusses, both are used, but American English prefers singular, where British English uses either, often with a slight nuance of meaning.

Secondly, there is the article: in the question Colleen linked, the collective noun was *India*, which is a name, so does not take an article. But *family* is a common noun. So in that light, it must be either *There are family* (plural, semantic agreement, less favoured in AmE) or *There is **a** family* (singular, syntactic agreement).

But thirdly, in colloquial British English (I think American too but I'm not sure) people often use *There's* as an invariant presentational, irrespective of number. So in that context *There's family* (plural with invariant "there's") would be natural, but only in informal contexts.

Comment: The flexibility of "there's" is covered pretty well in an answer to [There's vs There are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39181/9161).